# Could Fermat's Little Theorem be expanded to include some semiprimes for p?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Fermat's Little Theorem states that a^p%p=a. For example, if a=2, then 2^p%p=2 if p is any prime. That's all the theorem says. However, I tried plugging in 3p instead of p, and I got an interesting result. For all p that I tested (all primes up to 100), the modded result is 8 (or 2^3). I also tried 5 and 7, but the results didn't seem to have a clear pattern. Is it possible that some semiprimes combinations could be found through Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: I don't understand what your complete assertion is exactly. It's entirely obvious that $2^{3p}\equiv 8\pmod p$ for all $p$, because $$2^{3p}\equiv 2^p\cdot 2^p\cdot 2^p\equiv 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\pmod p$$

Comment: Sorry, the OP wasn't very clear. The assertion is 2^3p%3p=2^3. My question really was why does that always result in 8 whereas 2^5p%5p does not always equal 2^5 (e.g. p=7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting observation.

The point here is that $2\equiv -1\pmod 3$.

It follows from that that, for odd $p$, $$2^{3p}\equiv -1\pmod 3$$

Now, of course, $$2^{3p}\equiv 8 \pmod p$$  by Little Fermat.

Noting that $8\equiv -1\pmod 3$, we see  that the unique solution to this pair of congruences is $$2^{3p}\equiv 8\pmod {3p}$$
at least for $p>3$.

As you can see, however, this all depends on a number of numerical accidents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this was a great answer. However, I think it isn't necessarily a numerical accident. After seeing your proof, 2^3 (2^3p%3p=2^3) works, but so does 4^5 (4^5p%5p=4^5), 6^7, 8^9, etc. I wonder if this has any practical use. I can't really think of anything, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Yes, a similar phenomenon holds for $a^b$ if $a\equiv -1 \pmod b$.  That congruence is what drives the thing.